# What are those plain white rock cubes for?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

In each world (so far) there have been big, plain, white rock cubes. Cappy says something to the effect of "this is plain and probably doesn't do anything" but I'm not sure I believe him.

They look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’ll avoid spoilers and not give the plot reason, but basically they are used as end game content after you complete the final boss.

Per [Power Up Gaming](https://powerup-gaming.com/2017/10/27/super-mario-odyssey-metal-cubes-boxes/):

> After completing the story, if you return to any of the other worlds, Cappy should tell you that the cube is activated. If he doesn’t, it means that you’ve not yet completed enough of that world. You’ll need to defeat all bosses and sub-bosses for that world before the cube will activate.
>
> Once it is activated, head over to it and give it a ground pound, jump + <kbd>ZL</kbd> or <kbd>ZR</kbd>. The cube will shatter and add lots more Power Moons to the world.

It will add a significant amount of content to each world after you finish the game.

Comment: Neat! I'm almost to that point so that explains where all that extra comes from...

Comment: Yeah I'd say almost 50% of moons are locked behind those blocks, and they are only available after beating the campaign

Comment: You can also throw your hat at the cubes to activate them.