# How do I light the campfire in the Wooded Kingdom?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

After defeating Bowser and unlocking the [post-game content](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/320420/181240), I found an NPC next to a campfire in the Wooded Kingdom who said he needed fire to cook with. (This is north of The Odyssey next to Talkatoo)

[The map says that there's a Power Moon here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVCNO.png), but I can't figure out how to get it. How do I light this fork's campfire?

[image]

Comment: Are there any of the fire-throwing Koopas nearby you could lure in that direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Moon #64 - Hot, hot, hot from the Campfire***

Start at the **Iron Mountain Path, Station 8** checkpoint flag. From here, look immediately off the ledge with a railing to your left. You will see a cliff with some collapsing iron girder platforms, and below that another set of cliffs with a Fire Bro.

Capture him and you can easily make your way off the cliff to the campfire you need to light.

Here's a video showing the fastest way to grab the Moon, timestamped at the one you're looking for.